# how to enter a new line in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using reactbootstrap and I want to enter a new line. 
 doesn't seem to work.

```
{revision.notes.map(note => (
    <div key={note.id}>
        "{note.content}"
        <span className="pull-right">
            <a href={`/editor/${note.author.id}`}>
                <i>
                    —{note.author.name}
                </i>
            </a>
            <br/>
        </span>
        <br/>
    </div>

))}
```

[image: This is the output I am getting]

You can see it's messed up. Both author name are coming in same line. I want to have Note in one line and it's corresponding author name at the right side. If there is space for author name in same line after the note, then I want it there otherwise new line. How do I achieve it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FsgxkOOzQCGX4El5S0vVD_JjL5rQC4qO
This is the output I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `p` tag

The following should work.

```
{revision.notes.map(note => (
    <div key={note.id}>
        <p>{note.content}</p>
        <span className="pull-right">
            <a href={`/editor/${note.author.id}`}>
                <i>
                    —{note.author.name}
                </i>
            </a>
            <br/>
        </span>
        <br/>
    </div>
))}
```